# Is there a way to use current frame and total frames as vairables in a filter in ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to write a silly command to rotate a video clockwise through the entire thing. The only things I need is a variable to tell the filter the current frame number, and the total frame count.

Here's my planned command (`cf` = current frame, `tf` = total frames)

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf rotate=(cf*(tf/360))/PI*180 output.mp4`

Is there anyone willing to help?

Answer (score 0):

The [rotate filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rotate) says:

> The expressions for the angle and the output size can contain the
> following constants and functions:
>
> - `n` is the sequential number of the input frame, starting from 0. It is always NAN before the first frame is filtered.
> - `t` is time in seconds of the input frame, it is set to 0 when the filter is configured. It is always NAN before the first frame is
>   filtered.

There is no variable for total duration, but you can get the input file duration with `ffprobe`. See [How to get video duration in seconds?](https://superuser.com/a/945604/)

Example to make 1 complete clockwise rotation in 10 seconds:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "rotate=(2*PI*t)/10" -c copy output.mp4
```